# How can I use services like Midjourney to make conventionally unattractive people?

Tags: image-generation, text-to-image, image

I use Midjourney to be the dungeon master in DND and I have encountered an issue. I want to make a world that feels somewhat realistic, but every character I make art for turns out unrealistically good looking.

I am trying to have my world filled with normal looking people, not just models.

Example:[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for a negative prompt, which is the second field on [Stable Diffusion 2.1 Demo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/stabilityai/stable-diffusion):

[image: prompt: "Lumberjack headshot" negative prompt: "handsome, attractive"]

[image: prompt: "Blonde woman 20-year-old headshot photograph full color" negative prompt: "beautiful, attractive"]

[image: prompt: "Brown haired woman photograph" negative prompt: "beautiful, attractive, low quality"]

[image: prompt: "brown haired woman candid" negative: "beautiful, low quality"]

[image: prompt: "Amish teen headshot" negative prompt: "beautiful, attractive"]

This is a very quick image generator, so the quality is often lacking (but it's good for experimenting). Many other AI image generators support negative prompts too; in Midjourney, you add `--no x y z` to the end of your prompt to tell it to avoid x, y, and z.